# Can an application get notified when the debugger detaches?

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012

When detaching the VS debugger using F4 aka *Stop Debugging* does the VS debugger raise some signal or exception that can be caught in a C++ or C# application? Same question for when it attaches though that's of less use to me - although I guess that could be solved by having a seperate thread spin on `IsDebuggerPresent` in C++ for instance.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the debugger doesn't "announce itself".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no event sent from Visual studio. but you can simulate that like so:

```
      var t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
      {
        while (true)
        {
          if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
          {
            //Check if the IsAttached Changed raise a custom event DebuggerDetached
          }
          else
          {
            //Check if the IsAttached Changed raise a custom event DebuggerAttached
          }

          Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
      }));

      t.Start();
```

Comment: searched some more and indeed could not find events or so anywhere, so a solution like this is the only option.